# what does teacher.input(score[i], i); mean?

Tags: java, input

My coding looks like as follows:

```
public class teacher2 {
    Score[] Score;

    public teacher2() {
        Score = new Score[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < Score.length; i++)
            Score[i] = new Score();
    }

    public void input(float[] score, int id) {
        Score[id].setScore(score);
    }

    public void check() {
        int count;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            count = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < Score.length; j++) {
               if (Score[j].getScore(i) >=60)
               count++;
            }
            System.out.println("pass rate of class " + i + " is: " + (count /10.0) * 100 + "%");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        teacher2 teacher = new teacher2();
        float[][] score = {
                { 45, 56, 88, 96, 78 },
                { 77, 85, 65, 89, 75 },
                { 86, 96, 75, 98, 90 },
                { 52, 78, 95, 45, 25 },
                { 45, 12, 69, 88, 56 },
                { 45, 56, 88, 96, 78 },
                { 77, 85, 65, 89, 75 },
                { 86, 96, 75, 98, 90 },
                { 52, 78, 95, 45, 25 },
                { 45, 12, 69, 88, 56 },
        };      
        for (int i = 0; i <10; i++){
            teacher.input(score[i], i);
        }
        teacher.check();        
    }
}
```

1. I'm wondering what does `teacher.input(score[i], i);` mean, since when i search online with "input" keyword, all those coming out are about input.netline();
2. and for the last line, when we want to do check, there is no need to type coding, just type variable.check()?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *"Any help will be greatly appreciated!"* - Since you asked.  You need to fix your code's indentation, and obey the Java style rules for identifiers.  A Java class name should *always* start with an upper-case latter.

Answer (score 0):

It calls the method `input` in the object `teacher`. You've defined the method yourself further up in the code:

```
public void input(float[] score, int id){
    Score[id].setScore(score);
}
```

You have also defined the method `check` in the teacher object, that method accepts no parameters which is why you can just call it with an empty parameter list `check()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
teacher.input(score[i], i);
```

Calls the `input` method on the `teacher2` instance.

Not sure what you mean by "no need to type coding", the `check` method is what you want to run, yes?

Comment: i guess he is newer than a newbie and don't know that the code he copied already have the method input....